# error while trying to create Toast.makeText

Tags: java, android, apk, runtime-error, toast

I am developing a android app, i am facing force close issue when i am using "Toast.makeText" in my code, when i remove the line its working perfectly. Can anyone tell me the problem in this. i am pasting the screenshot of Log Cat.

[image: Screenshot of Log Cat]

Comment: Which line of code is creating the problem ? The one you have commented or the one which is still there ?

Comment: @swayam the line which i have commented is the only line which is causing the error.

Comment: Little help for you. Activity class is extended from Context and your field Context context in Activity is rabbish.

Comment: @IlyaDemidov i didn't get it what you're trying to say.. can u clarify a bit.

Comment: Your ex.getMessage().toString() is also wrong , because in many exceptions message will be null. check for null and then do a tostring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sending SMS..Please Wait..!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: If you are inside an Activity, then you can. Toast.makeText() expects the context of the Activity. So, if you are defining anonymous objects in your Activity, using `this` there would take the instance of the class for which you are creating the anonymous object. So, in those cases you need to mention the Activity. So, to always be on the safer side, you can always use the instance of the Activity by mentioning the name of the activity.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Class Activity is extended from class Context. To have reference to Context in Activity is  not correct. When you want to show Toast, just put your activtiy as Context.

```
Class MainActivtiy extends Activty {
...

    Toast.makeText(this,"Sending SMS..Please Wait..!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
...
}
```

If call in internal class, do just like that :

```
Class MainActivtiy extends Activty {
...
     onClick (View v) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivty.this,"Sending SMS..Please          Wait..!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
...
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`context` variable has no value.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.context = this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getApplicationContext() or Your_Class_Name.this  rather than using this.context then i think this problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution..It goes like this

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sending SMS..Please wait..!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting or accepting the answer which solves your problem rather than adding the same thing as your own answer. Cheers. :)

Comment: @swayam i found the solution on some other site and hence mentioned it here.

Comment: Yes my friend, I do understand. But you might also have noticed that my answer is exactly the same and it was posted before you did. We are helping you here, atleast give us some credit! :)

Comment: @swayam i have one other problem/query can u help me on that?

Comment: Sure. But here on Stackoverflow it is better to ask only one question per post. So, I guess it's better if you could just give me the link to your new question and I would surely help you out. :)

Comment: @swayam i have created the new question. link is as below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235310/create-alert-dialog-on-receiving-sms

Comment: @swayam can i send you a request on facebook?

Comment: Sure. No problem! :) And I have added an answer to the other question. Hope that helps you.

Comment: @swayam i've sent you a request on facebook

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Sending SMS..Please Wait..!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing context from a Thread with this.context is giving you NULLPointerException, as Thread class structure belong to classic Java and does not posses the Android Context. For example, you tried to access like 'this.context' which is null. As @SamirMangroliya suggested use current activity or use Android way of multithreading ASynchTask which posses context reference

Note this was a comment, but could't find the original response so here it is