# create alert dialog on receiving sms

Tags: android, sms, android-alertdialog

I am creating a app for android which sends sms using gateways like "way2sms.com", "fullonsms.com", i have succeeded in sending messages from those gateways, now i want to take another step, i.e "SMS DELIVERY REPORT". I have a basic idea about how will i do this. When i will send sms to the number selected by the user after that i will send one sms back to user with some formatted text for e.g. "SMSDELIVERYREPORT". What i want to do is that when the user receives such message instead of normal notification which we get when we receive normal sms, the application of create a Alert Dialog saying "Message successfully delivered." Please guide me in fulfilling this task. and also how can i make sure that this messages do not go in users normal message inbox.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android) tutorial, when i was creating something similiar!

Just jump to Handle Received SMS!

Comment: but how do i stop those messages from going to user's inbox?

Comment: simply add  abortBroadcast(); into your broadcast reciever (after checking if it's the right sms)